# Why is this code used to draw a raycast vector not displaying the vector correctly?

Tags: game-development, pascal, lazarus

Following the examples given in the Pascal-driven Castle Game Engine for drawing a mesh, I tried to draw a raycast vector visually using this particular piece of code for reference:

```
  procedure CreateMesh;
  begin
    Mesh := TCastleRenderUnlitMesh.Create(true);
    Mesh.SetVertexes([
      Vector4(-1, -1, -1, 1),
      Vector4( 1, -1, -1, 1),
      Vector4( 1,  1, -1, 1),
      Vector4(-1,  1, -1, 1),

      Vector4(-1, -1,  1, 1),
      Vector4( 1, -1,  1, 1),
      Vector4( 1,  1,  1, 1),
      Vector4(-1,  1,  1, 1)
    ], false);
    Mesh.SetIndexes([
      // line loop on Z = -1
      0, 1,
      1, 2,
      2, 3,
      3, 0,

      // line loop on Z = 1
      4, 5,
      5, 6,
      6, 7,
      7, 4,

      // connect Z = -1 with Z = 1
      0, 4,
      1, 5,
      2, 6,
      3, 7
    ]);

    // Later on in the code
    CreateMesh;
```

I was told on [this](https://forum.castle-engine.io/t/need-help-making-collision-with-ground-work-correctly/1025/64) particular thread, when I asked for clarification, that the numbers in "SetIndexes" indicate the order to draw the lines in correctly like I guessed, and that SetVertices set the vertices that you draw from and to. That is fine.

However, when I saw that "SetVertices" as it was in the example above didn't accept parameters and I needed parameters to get the player character's location precisely, I asked if it was okay to create my own function with parameters.

I didn't get a response, because they wanted me to figure things out for my self there to actually learn, which is fine, but knew the resourceful and responsible thing to do was to look up the function in the manual and see if it is pre-defined with a specific number of parameters,

But fortunately it wasn't, so I assumed it was probably a piece of code customly defined by the user in that case, rather than pre-programed into the engine's language.

I guessed then, that I could use the above code for reference to make my own custom SetVertices with parameters, and use the parameter's coordinates for the inputs of the vector coordinates, exactly like this:

```
  procedure CreateMesh(const AvatarTransform: TCastleTransform);
  begin
    Mesh := TCastleRenderUnlitMesh.Create(true);
    Mesh.SetVertexes([
      Vector4(0.0, AvatarTransform.Translation.Y, 0.0, 1.0),
      Vector4(0.0, (AvatarTransform.Translation.Y - AvatarTransform.Direction.Y), 0.0, 1.0),
    ], false);
    Mesh.SetIndexes([
      // line loop on Z = -1
      0, 1
    ]);

 
 // Line somewhere later down the code; I guessed the problem was
 // not having the correct amount of inputs to match the procedure 
 // definition above, but it still doesn't draw anything afterward

CreateMesh;
```

Even though I made sure to make sure to actually define the parameter in the function declaration, and follow examples of the game engine for doing the correct format and syntax, it still compiles fine but never actually draws anything.

Does anyone with expertise in this kind of thing know why this is?

The full project for reference download is here, as this code is only one small part of it:

[Link to full project in a ZIP archive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b-aukNCEtTM09vVPh0rKv_9p5pFgwNOq/view?usp=sharing)

I followed the directions of a particular example for the thing I needed, and expected it to work the same.

However, it ended up not working at all, which is why I am confused.

Comment: I think cause the Raycast Direction has a negative number for the coordinate, I should have added rather than subtracted, but either way it should have drawn something.

Comment: Silly me, I think I figured it out. Not only that, but also I didn't actually specify any parameters when I called the function later on down the code.

Comment: If that is indeed correct, I think we can lock the topic because there is no need to discuss a problem with a found solution?

Comment: Although I did find out I didn't use a function with parameters correctly and fixed that, it still doesn't draw correctly - therefore the problem is not fixed and still there. It just doesn't make any sense, given how I followed all the rest of the directions exactly - the only thing I changed was to specify that the SetVertices procedure/function will take inputs, whereas that wasn't true earlier.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic . Note the first numbered paragraph: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.* See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The code you have posted, doesn't qualify as a minimal reproducible example as it can't be copy-pasted to be run by us. I repeat and emphasize the necessity of a **Minimal Reproducible Example**.

Comment: *Facepalm* But you can say the same thing about literally any code - for example basic C++ code doesn't compile without the proper compiler, and this code isn't any different, you can in fact copy paste it into the correct Lazarus compiler and it should run fine.

Comment: Did you mean it's because it's part of a larger project, and I should have included all the code and the project file itself directly for easier usage, rather than having people figure out how to download it themself? That's a valid critique and thank you for it.

Comment: Please don't be argumentative. Your question doen't fit on StackOverflow unless you can rewrite it. I repeat the essence: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.** Note the phrase: ***and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*** I assume you know what *short* means.

Comment: You say: *you can in fact copy paste it into the correct Lazarus compiler and it should run fine.* I don't think so as there are references to other units in the uses clause.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly your point, namely that it was referencing other things on top of not being as short as possible. Makes sense and I'm sorry for not understanding at first.

Comment: I think too, the piece of code I presented is the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem in the question body, because if you omitted any of the lines like "unit" or the lines with the word "matrix" then the code wouldn't compile correctly after being copy pasted.

Comment: I understand it looks like a lot to read at first, but every line does in fact count. Also, making a point that is logically sound is not the same as being argumentative for no reason.

Comment: However, I did give a link to the full project for reference after you pointed out I need it, cause I knew that was important. If you wanted all the code of the project in one post, it would be A: impossible to copy paste in one file because it is intentionally split into multiple files and B: it would be even longer to read, which is what you don't like already.

Comment: Am I perhaps misunderstanding, that I can just copy paste the lines to not exactly over ride the entire code in the file, but just the appropriate parts (like I only need to give the problem lines and not the entire file, because you guys will be smart enough to figure out where the problem lines are)? That makes more sense and again I'm sorry for misunderstanding that as well.

Comment: I edited the post accordingly. Can someone either lock the thread and we can start this  from scratch after I have walked away and understood what shortest question really means, or do you guys want to answer the post directly with a solution and lock the thread after that?

Comment: I tried doing the correct formatting for multi-line block comments, /* Like this */, but it didn't show it in grayed out code format correctly. That is really weird, but I knew I could just use single line comments each line, which is what I did.

Comment: I also get that I can learn by example too from upvoted questions, and now I know 100% that by "shortest question" you meant only the lines that are problematic, and not the entire code. I am sorry for the confusion and will always make sure to remember that in the future. Is there anything else that you think needs fixing, or is that the only problem, that my question was too lengthy and didn't include the correct amount of resources to reproduce exactly?

Comment: For the last time (on my side): provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example I repeat the keywords in that article: **Minimal**, **Complete**, **Reproducible**. Please read carefully and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Okay, I read the guidelines thoroughly as well as the example posts to learn completely. I made sure it is minimal as possible by including only code relevant to the problem at hand and not all the code at once, made sure that I used space for tabs for readability, as well as used comments, made sure the problem is in the question itself with code formatting, made sure to describe the problem without vagueness, made sure to be straightforward and not go off on off topic topics, and verified the code still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Perhaps the "SetIndices" with the huge list of non-vector numbers I can omit, but again that's a little gray area/iffy because the "SetIndices" is part of the code that tells the mesh how to draw itself once you analyze how the example at the very top is set up.

Comment: **Minimal**? Yes, but too minimal. **Complete**? No can't be compiled, neither run. **Reproducible**? No, because doesn't exhibit the problem you are asking about. Sorry, you lost me.

Comment: *Facepalm* A: If you are going  to tell me that there is something like too minimal, I will have to take my business elsewhere - by definiton minimal means that you have as little code as necessary to re-create the problem, because all the rest is irrelevant to the problem at hand. B: I still advocate it can be compiled if you use the project linked and paste the lines in the appropriate file specified. C: It does in fact exhibit the problem I am talking about, because I posted all the lines exactly as they were, complete with the indenting necessary and comments, to show you how to reproduce.

Comment: And this isn't being argumentative - this is pointing out actual facts that the guidelines tell me and the dictionary defintion of what the words usually mean to all English speakers.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer to your main question is that you didn't call "Mesh.Render(pmLines)". Possibly you just forgot it, which explains why you don't see anything.

This answer is somewhat a guess, as you don't show the full source code, only a snippet that doesn't compile. I see you have been pointed to the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example already in the comments. Your "Link to full project in a ZIP archive" is not publicly readable.

If you are unsure how TCastleRenderUnlitMesh works, please:

- Experiment with CGE examples, in particular "examples/research_special_rendering_methods/test_rendering_opengl_capabilities" ( https://github.com/castle-engine/castle-engine/tree/master/examples/research_special_rendering_methods/test_rendering_opengl_capabilities ) is using TCastleRenderUnlitMesh. You refer to it in your post, so I believe you found it. Note how https://github.com/castle-engine/castle-engine/blob/master/examples/research_special_rendering_methods/test_rendering_opengl_capabilities/code/gamemymesh.pas has "Mesh.Render(pmLines)" call.
- See the API docs, https://castle-engine.io/apidoc/html/CastleRenderPrimitives.TCastleRenderUnlitMesh.html . It says explicitly

> The things you really have to set before rendering are:
>
> - Vertexes, using SetVertexes.
> - Matrix (combined projection * camera * model transformation) ModelViewProjection.
> - That's it, the rest has sensible defaults. You can just call Render.

This question is a duplicate of a question you asked on Lazarus forums: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,66238.0.html . I give there more details. There are even more details in the Castle Game Engine forum thread(s) where we try to help you, in https://forum.castle-engine.io/t/need-help-making-collision-with-ground-work-correctly/1025/70 .